# Image Zoom using uiscrollview working unexpectedly. swift

Tags: ios, swift, image

I was developing an app in which a user adds a photo and edits it. When the image is added to `imageView` and zoomed it works fine but when I add a new image, unexpectedly the scrollView increases in length and the image is viewed in the middle of the scrollView has coded, but the scrollView increases in size. I have to scroll to the middle to view the image. Below is the code I am using.

```
 @IBAction func addPhotoTrigered(_ sender: Any) {
     addPhotoCall()
    }

    func addPhotoCall() {
        print("dsds")
        let image = UIImagePickerController()
        image.delegate = self
        image.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
        image.allowsEditing = false
        self.present(image, animated: true) {
        }
    }
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        imagePic = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage
           addImageView.isHidden = true
            imageView.image = imagePic
            newImageButton.isHidden = false
            photoStatus = true
            imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.center
        imageView.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: imagePic!.size.width, height: imagePic!.size.height))
        print(imageView.frame)
        scrollView.contentSize = imagePic!.size
        let scrollViewFrame = scrollView.frame
        let scrollWidth = scrollViewFrame.size.width / scrollView.contentSize.width
        let scrollHeight = scrollViewFrame.size.height / scrollView.contentSize.height
        let minScale = min(scrollHeight, scrollWidth)
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = minScale
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.zoomScale = minScale
        centreScrollViewContent()
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
    func centreScrollViewContent() {
        let boundSize = scrollView.bounds.size
        var contentFrame = imageView.frame
        if contentFrame.size.width < boundSize.width {
            contentFrame.origin.x = (boundSize.width - contentFrame.size.width) / 2
        } else {
            contentFrame.origin.x = 0
        }
        if contentFrame.size.height < boundSize.height {
            contentFrame.origin.y = (boundSize.height - contentFrame.size.height) / 2
        } else {
            contentFrame.origin.y = 0
        }
        imageView.frame = contentFrame
    }


    func scrollViewDidZoom(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        centreScrollViewContent()
    }
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

        return imageView
    }
@IBAction func newImageTrigered(_ sender: Any) {
    imageView.image = nil
    addImageView.isHidden = false
    newImageButton.isHidden = true
}
```

please fix the code. I have tried many ways but was not able to understand why its happening.

Answer (score 0):

make an outlet from your scroll view and put delegate self and add uiscrollViewDelegate to viewcontroller and then it should work 
i have a sample code to

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self
    updateZoomFor(size: scrollView.bounds.size)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

func updateZoomFor(size: CGSize) {
    let widthScale = size.width / imageView.bounds.width
    let heightScale = size.height / imageView.bounds.height
    let scale = min(widthScale, heightScale)
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = scale
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 5
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

Comment: This all things i have already done. and it exits in the code(did not add the complete code)